# Playframework2.3をIntelliJ IDEA14経由でRunするとエラーが出て起動できない

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea

Playframework2.3（Scala）のプロジェクトをIntelliJ IDEA14経由でRunすると以下のエラーが出て起動ができません。
※IDEA13ならば問題なく動作しました

調べるとSbtが怪しそうな気がするのですが…

どなたか対処法をご存じないでしょうか？

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djline.terminal=none -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dsbt.global.base=/private/var/folders/9k/hkj6fc4d2f91tjk31kwk68p40000gn/T/sbt-global-plugin0stub -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -classpath "/Users/seijiro/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar" xsbt.boot.Boot "project project_name" ~run
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/seijiro/Dropbox/Develop/Project/project_name/project_name/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/seijiro/Dropbox/Develop/Project/project_name/project_name/project/}project_name-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.3.7 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.7 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.2-GA ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support_2.10;2.3.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scalacheck#scalacheck_2.10;1.11.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10;1.12.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-scalaz-core_2.10.0-RC3;6.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving junit#junit;4.11 ...
[info] Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.2.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.mozilla#rhino;1.7R4 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.javascript#closure-compiler;v20130603 ...
[info] Resolving org.json#json;20090211 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm-agent;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.3.175 ...
[info] Resolving net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-twirl;1.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-compiler_2.10;1.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.10;1.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-parser_2.10;1.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-core;2.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.5.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.7.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.4.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.tukaani#xz;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.vafer#jdeb;1.3 ...
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.tukaani#xz;1.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-core;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-model;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-utils;3.0.17 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-settings;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-settings-builder;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-interpolation;1.19 ...
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-component-annotations;1.5.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.sonatype.plexus#plexus-sec-dispatcher;1.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.sonatype.plexus#plexus-cipher;1.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-repository-metadata;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-artifact;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-plugin-api;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.sisu#org.eclipse.sisu.plexus;0.0.0.M5 ...
[info] Resolving javax.enterprise#cdi-api;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving javax.annotation#jsr250-api;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving javax.inject#javax.inject;1 ...
[info] Resolving org.sonatype.sisu#sisu-guice;3.1.3 ...
[info] Resolving aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.sisu#org.eclipse.sisu.inject;0.0.0.M5 ...
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-classworlds;2.5.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-model-builder;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-aether-provider;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.aether#aether-api;0.9.0.M2 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.aether#aether-spi;0.9.0.M2 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.aether#aether-util;0.9.0.M2 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.aether#aether-impl;0.9.0.M2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.ant#ant;1.9.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.ant#ant-launcher;1.9.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.bouncycastle#bcpg-jdk15on;1.51 ...
[info] Resolving org.bouncycastle#bcprov-jdk15on;1.51 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-js-engine;1.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#jse_2.10;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-contrib_2.10;2.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-remote_2.10;2.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving io.netty#netty;3.8.0.Final ...
[info] Resolving com.google.protobuf#protobuf-java;2.5.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.uncommons.maths#uncommons-maths;1.2.2a ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-cluster_2.10;2.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-persistence-experimental_2.10;2.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.iq80.leveldb#leveldb;0.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.iq80.leveldb#leveldb-api;0.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-all;1.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni;1.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.hawtjni#hawtjni-runtime;1.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-osx;1.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-linux32;1.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-linux64;1.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-win32;1.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni-win64;1.5 ...
[info] Resolving io.apigee.trireme#trireme-core;0.7.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving io.apigee.trireme#trireme-node10src;0.7.5 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-json_2.10;1.2.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-scala_2.10;1.1.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-simple;1.7.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#npm_2.10;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#npm;1.3.26 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#webjars-locator;0.14 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.3.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.3.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.3.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-web;1.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-webdriver;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#webdriver_2.10;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-client;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-can;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-io;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-util;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-http;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-httpx;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.jvnet.mimepull#mimepull;1.9.4 ...
[info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.14 ...
[info] Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.1 ...
[info] Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.1 ...
[info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 ...
[info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.2.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.9 ...
[info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.14 ...
[info] Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
[info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
[info] Resolving net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.20 ...
[info] Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.13 ...
[info] Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-websocket;8.1.14.v20131031 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.14.v20131031 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.14.v20131031 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.14.v20131031 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-coffeescript;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#coffee-script-node;1.7.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#mkdirp;0.3.5 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-less;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#less-node;1.6.0-1 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#source-map;0.1.31-2 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#amdefine;0.1.0-1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-jshint;1.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#jshint-node;2.4.1-1 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#underscorejs;1.5.2-2 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#console-browserify;0.1.6-1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-rjs;1.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#rjs;2.1.11-1-trireme ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-mocha;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#mocha;1.17.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#debug;0.7.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.webjars#diff;1.0.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logging;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#process;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#relation;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#persist;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.10;0.4.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cross;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.3.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.46 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to project_name (in build file:/Users/seijiro/Dropbox/Develop/Project/project_name/project_name/)
[error] Not a valid project ID: project_name
[error] project project_name
[error]                       ^

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA14.1の更新とScalaプラグインを最新版に更新したら解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJのScalaプラグインをアップデートして、プロジェクト内の.idea, idea_modulesを削除。

その後にimport projectを行ったら解決しました。

ただし、補完ができませんでした

以下参考
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Byo2aLE4INE

Comment: activator ideaすればいいかも